# How can do a contract to Approve user manipuler her tokens?

Tags: solidity

Like I have own token
And I develope an Dapp to transfer between us my own personal token.
To do that I have to Approve and then use transferFrom, aren't¿
I check some nft games and always, then force my to approve before play.
I have tryed to do that but if I have
Contrat MyToken

Contract MyDapp

When I save user address to Approve, I send Approve from MyDapp to MyToken, then approve no works.

How can I do that? or what is the good way to do that?
Thanks

Comment: User must approve with the tokens contract directly.

Comment: How? from remix I did it manualty but from Dapp when the 1rs action is Approve and you have to pay some dolars 0,1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to approve compound USDT with [this contract address on Rinkeby](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xd9ba894e0097f8cc2bbc9d24d308b98e36dc6d02)

your JavaScript code with ethers.js library (it could be python or java too, library is important) (Note that I only use front-end and I personally know nothing about back-end)

```
const ethers = require('ethers');

const USDTInterface = ['function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool)'];
const USDTAddress = '0xD9BA894E0097f8cC2BBc9D24D308b98e36dc6D02';
const yourContractAddress = YOUR_DAPP_CONTRACT_ADDRESS;

let provider;
let signer;
let signerAddress;
let USDTContract;

const startFunction = async () => {
    await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts'});
    await ethereum.request({ method: 'wallet_switchEthereumChain', params:[{chainId: '0x4'}]});
    provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
    signer = provider.getSigner();
    signerAddress = await signer.getAddress();
    USDTContract = await new ethers.Contract(USDTAddress, USDTInterface, signer);
}
startFunction();

async function approveUSDT(){
    USDTContract.approve(yourContractAddress, BigInt("9007199254740990")**3n);
}
//Whenever this function is called, a transaction request is sent to user's metamask and whenever
//user confirms it, it is approved!
```