# Solidity with Ropsten Test Network - Uncaught Error: invalid address

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js, truffle, metamask

I was following some tutorials of d-apps and the link to the tutorial is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkZ6iYnSDRw

I tried to connect my front end script with metamask, using the Ropsten network.

What have I done wrong?

When the page was loading, the variable that is meant to be displayed in the HTML file (there is nothing wrong with the HTML file), was displayed without issues. However, after I click a button to trigger the function which changes that variable's name, the error below appeared in the console:

Uncaught Error: invalid address

at v (web3.min.js:2)

at l (web3.min.js:2)

at web3.min.js:2
at Array.map ()

at i.formatInput (web3.min.js:2)

at i.toPayload (web3.min.js:2)
at r.e [as sendTransaction] (web3.min.js:2)

at c.sendTransaction (web3.min.js:2)

at c.execute (web3.min.js:2)

at HTMLFormElement. ((index):125)

```
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
      } else {

        web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider (MY_INFURA_API));

      
      }
      console.log("web3 is:",web3)
      // Set Account
      web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];

      // Set Contract Abi
      var contractAbi = [
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "candidateName",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_name",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "name": "setCandidate",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "constructor"
    }
]
      
      
      
      
      
      // Add Your Contract ABI here!!!

      // Set Contract Address 
      // for ropston
      var contractAddress = // Add Your Contract address here!!!
      


      // Set the Contract
      var contract = web3.eth.contract(contractAbi).at(contractAddress);

      // Display Candidate Name
      contract.candidateName(function(err, candidateName) {
        $('#candidateName').html(candidateName);
      });

      // Change the Candidate Name
      $('form').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(contract)
        contract.setCandidate($('input').val());
    
      })
```

I realised I was quite careless, and after I placed the address inside the variable "web3.eth.defaultAccount", the invalid address issue seemed to be resolved. However, I get the error as shown below.
[image]

Comment: Where is the code of the button to connect to metamask?! Also you have shown your infura API which others can use it, change it into `MY_INFURA_API`

Comment: thks! and there was not a button to connect to metamask; how do we connect to metamask? Actually i intend it to be automatically connected to metamask

Comment: I know in ethes.js, it is a bit different and I did not see anyone answer your question so you don't mind if you use ethers.js?!

Comment: i might need some help on that ^

Comment: I guess both have same methods but there is a bit difference, so you yourself must figure it out. Also if you have some questions about ethers.js, I would gladly help you as much as I know

Comment: I refer you to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69099317/how-can-do-a-contract-to-approve-user-manipuler-her-tokens/69102152#69102152 .Just note that, this code is for Rinkeby network and all addresses used in it, for Ropsten network you must change `params:[{chainId: '0x4'}]` into `params:[{chainId: '0x3'}]` in line 13

Comment: update: it turns out that i used 1 of the wrong parameters (my web3.eth.defaultAccount was undefined). However after fixing that problem, i encountered "The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available"

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it, provide image of the error

Comment: hi i have edited the post and the image of the error is as shown in the edited post

Comment: Is your web3 package installed completely and without any error?!

Comment: yes; update: i solved it; i found this: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/66345/how-to-use-sendtransaction-to-send-erc20-tokens-through-metamask/66368